# Create a Query to Combine Data from Two Tables with Similar data

Tags: sql-server-2012

In need an aggregate result of two similar tables without getting duplicates.

The tables have similar structure. (date,billed_number,carrier_id,duration...)
tables are 2019-01-29 and 2019-01-30

I've tried UNION of the same query but I get duplicate entries.

```
 select billed_number, sum(CASE WHEN [account_billed_duration] > 0 THEN 1 END) AS completed
 from alex4..[2019-01-29]
 where billed_number = '702640'
 and carrier_id = 171
 group by billed_number

 union all

 select billed_number, sum(CASE WHEN [account_billed_duration] > 0 THEN 1 END) AS completed
 from alex4..[2019-01-30]
 where billed_number = '702640'
 and carrier_id = 171
 group by billed_number
```

In this example I'm only using tables  ([2019-01-29] and [2019-01-30])
   I also need to be able to combine more than two tables.

Result:
billed_number,completed
702640  3735
702640  3539

Expected Result:
billed_number, completed
702640  7274

Answer (score 0):

Use union not union all indeed combine all results with duplicates

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the reply. I actually tried both UNION and UNION ALL and got the same result.

I was up last night until I figured it out. 
A sub query did the trick...

```
 SELECT  distinct  billed_number , sum(completed)as comp , FROM    (
        SELECT  [billed_number], 
        sum(CASE WHEN [account_billed_duration] > 0 THEN 1 END) AS completed,
        sum(CASE WHEN [account_billed_duration] = 0 THEN 1 END) AS failed
        FROM alex4..[2019-01-29]
 where billed_number = '702640'
 and carrier_id = 171
 group by billed_number --,account_billed_duration
        UNION
        SELECT  [billed_number], 
        sum(CASE WHEN [account_billed_duration] > 0 THEN 1 END) AS completed,
        sum(CASE WHEN [account_billed_duration] = 0 THEN 1 END) AS failed
        FROM    alex4..[2019-01-30]
 where billed_number = '702640'
 and carrier_id = 171
 group by billed_number --, account_billed_duration
    ) Q
    group by billed_number
```

Once again thank you for the reply :-)